# would like to download this video with downloadhelper but cannot

Tags: firefox, download, youtube, firefox-extensions, flv

I am trying to download this video with  downloadhelper, the firefox extension
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28qwcVPNy3E
but I just get audio only.

This is particularly with this video clip.

The solution must use Downloadhelper, the firefox extension.

The solution must be tested to successfully download that video not just the audio of it!

If you do succeed, then the question is, why am I not succeeding in it?

This answer is not a duplicate of something already answered, since i'm asking specifically for regarding downloadhelper firefox extension, and a mysterious problem of audio only, specific to this clip.

Added-
It seems the downloaded file does include Video(even though the 10min clip is only 20MB). It wasn't playing before, but it is now. I haven't re-downloaded it.  Before it was just playing audio and displaying a blue screen with no text when I played it in VLC.

Comment: Whatare you using to play it back? Do you mean "downloadhelper"? Which file are you downloading the .mp4 or the .flv?

Comment: i'd like the flv

Comment: flv @ 360 works just fine using Win7-64, VLC media player (1.2.0-git-20101106-1331 Twoflower). What version are you using? How old are your video drivers?

Comment: @Tog Thanks for trying.  This is -very strange- it seems now the files that weren't playing, are playing. Before and now i'm using VLC.  So maybe it was VLC playing up before for some reason.

Comment: I found this thread on the problem of blue screen and just audio http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=40907  I suppose I could better know what the problem was if I could reproduce it but the link doesn't elaborate much.

Comment: You say the extension you are using is DownloadHelper and then you later say VideoHelper.  The DownloadHelper extension can not be used for what you're asking, and youtube is designed specifically to prevent such downloading methods.  Other extensions exist specifically to download video that work fine.

Comment: @AlanSE corrected it. i meant DownloadHelper, see my comment from mar 2011 to S.gfx's answer (I initially mistakenly called it videohelper in the whole answer. then changed it to downloadherlper and left a reference.  Looks like some wrote that downloadhelper is fine for them even if it didn't work for me.  If you actually mentioned the other extensions then that'd be helpful. It wouldn't be an answer to the question which was specific about downloadhelper,  but it'd be a very useful comment anyway.

Comment: these ones not free.  WM Recorder is pretty good if you have issues with these things. It just downloads what you play if you point it at the screen so can't fail. only thing more reliable would be mobile phone pointed at screen. riptiger is good.   a free one is streamtransport which works sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As Tog might be suspecting, if you are downloading the mp4, it might be just that you don't have certain video codec. You might use some free tool to check which codec is using that mp4 file and then download and install it. This can happen more often if you are using MS Media Player and have only default codecs installed. VLC player, which supports by itself a lot of formats and codecs, might be a good way to check if is this issue, you can just download [here](http://www.videolan.org), it's free.

Comment: Have you tried it? You may find you have the same problem as me. I've tried flv wmv mp4  it's all just audio.  And yes i'm using VLC.

Comment: I wrote in the question "The solution must be tested to successfully download that video not just the audio of it!"

Comment: then "If you do succeed, then the question is, why am I not succeeding in it?" but anyhow, onto why.. the reason you give is not the reason. As I said, it's this particular video. Many others i've tried are ok.

Comment: Well, actually could be that a mp4 plays fine in a player, but another compressed(different codec, etc) diferently may not. That's why I mentioned the codecs matter. Sorry, I dont have now installed that firefox extension(others probably wont, either) to make a full test and then the analysis :). Was mostly to see if a fast check of the codec might lead to a solution. Good luck! :)

Comment: BTW, you mention Videohelper... In case you don't know there's a very good extension for this, called DownloadHelper. If you meant actually this name, you might wish to change your question so you get more chances to get help for solving this :)

Comment: @S.gfx ta, i've corrected my question